# Limiting OpenVPN bandwidth

Tags: linux, openvpn

I'd like to give users a certain amount of traffic. Let's say user `A` gets 1 GB and user `B` get 5 GB.

I have a great script which does log all this info, however this script is called when the user disconnects (`client-disconnect`).

Now, my problem is the following: what if user `A` uses up 1 GB of data and simply never disconnects? He would be able to use thousands of GB's. Is there any way run a specific script periodically within OpenVPN (so no `crontab`, since OpenVPN passes environment variables).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should enable the [management interface](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/79-management-interface.html) on your OpenVPN server.

```
management 127.0.0.1 6001
```

Then write a program that you will periodically run from cron or something.  The script will connect to the management port, issue the `status` command, parse the data and store it somewhere that you can use by your other scripts that disconnect clients, or prevent access.  You can also issue disconnects via the management port.